# MySQL Query Length

Tags: php, mysql

I have more than 400 000 id's in NOT IN statement. Whether it will execute or not ?

```
$query = "
   SELECT
      *
   FROM
       table_name
   WHERE
       my_field_id NOT IN(
           34535345,3453451234,234242345,3465465,12234234,23435465,122343,345435,3453454,
           34535345,3453451234,234242345,3465465,12234234,23435465,122343,345435,3453454,
           34535345,3453451234,234242345,3465465,12234234,23435465,122343,345435,3453454,
           34535345,3453451234,234242345,3465465,12234234,23435465,122343,345435,3453454,
           34535345,3453451234,234242345,3465465,12234234,23435465,122343,345435,3453454,
           34535345,3453451234,234242345,3465465,12234234,23435465,122343,345435,3453454
       )
";
```

Comment: @miqdad ali can u tell me the execution time of this query it seems intrseting to me :)

Comment: @Rinzler: this query most likely produces table full scan. So the execution time depends on the table size

Comment: @xdazz These id's I am getting from another database ...

Comment: @Rinzler i didn't tried this query.. first I have to confirm this willn't make my server down..

Comment: @zerkms ya i know that but has he is saying lets assume there are 4 lakh ids in not in statements then what be the time taken ? any other better way to optimise it came to my mind :)

Comment: @Rinzler: almost the same time it takes to full scan the table, and a bit more for parsing the query

Comment: Without knowing how many rows are in table_name and whether or not the my_field_id column is indexed, there is absolutely no way at all to tell how long this would take.  What I will say is that unless you have more than a couple or three million rows, though, it's is *highly* unlikely that this query would cause any performance problems. Even a full table scan should return relatively quickly since it's a pretty simple query. I don't know what you mean by "4 lakh", is that a number?

Comment: @King Skippus: "or not the my_field_id column is indexed, " --- this changes nothing, it will be a full scan, because of `NOT IN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will (you could try that yourself without asking here actually). There is no reasonable limit for sql query string.

But you should keep in mind the more ids you add - the slower the query will be

PS: the only mysql setting you may be interested in is `max_allowed_packet`. From what I remember it is the only parameter that could bring some issues on extra-large queries

Comment: Thanks .... I din't tried this because, I afraid of this query will make my server down ... That's why first I am confirming :)

Comment: @Miqdad Ali: don't you have a development server?!

Answer (score 0):

As I know the IN clause in MySQL does not have limitations, you may write as many id as you want. Agree with zerkms about the performance and `max_allowed_packet` variable.

As a workaround - try to populate another table (maybe temporary) with indexed `id` with your values, and then loin these two tables using JOIN clause.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the limit is 1024 characters for NOT IN. If you use a sub-select there is no limit. You could populate a memory table with the id's, get them with a sub-select in the query and drop the memory table afterwards. This may even be faster.